# Is it possible to change "return" key to "done" on keyboard with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I didn't find any link or guide to change the "return" key to "done" when keyboard open for TextField in SwiftUI.

Is it possible now without customising UITextField?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change 'Return' button function to 'Done' in swift in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886720/change-return-button-function-to-done-in-swift-in-uitextview)

Comment: No, they are using UIKit and I am looking for an answer for SwiftUI

Comment: I am looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121756/swiftui-how-to-navigate-through-textfields-by-clicking-on-return-button-from-k but without UIKit.

Answer (score 120):

## iOS 15

You can change the return key for each `textField` with a simple modifier called: `submitLabel` that takes the return key type:

[image]
<sub>Image from WWDC21</sub>

Also, as you can see, you can have a callback to handle the return key press action just like the old `textFieldShouldReturn` function that is accessible by `.onSubmit` modifier.

<sub>⚠️ Seems like there is a bug  on Xcode 13 beta 1 that prevents this modifier from working in some situations.</sub>

Comment: Does it work for you? It doesn't for me and I wonder if there a bug or something...

Comment: Did you check on iOS 15?

Comment: Ok, I just find out that it doesn't work in a sheet. Without the sheet, it works fine.

Comment: Is it possible to stop the keyboard from dismissing when the submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 37):

#### Update

There is now a better solution. In iOS 15 you can now add a `.submitLabel(.done)` modifier. Please see Mojtaba's answer for more details.

---

#### Old Answer

The best way I found was to just add the package [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to your project.

After doing so add in `import Introspect` anywhere in your project files.

Then add one of their View Modifiers to your `Textfield` to achieve what you want. I believe this is what you want though ⤵

```swift
.introspectTextField { textfield in
  textfield.returnKeyType = .done
}
```

#### What Does Introspect Do?

It exposes UIKit to be used in SwiftUI. So that `Textfield` object you see above there has access to all of `UITextfield`'s functionality! This is a package though so be aware it could break in the future but for now this is a good option.

It's just nice because it saves you from making your own UIKit wrapper for every View.

Comment: This is such an awesome pod, thank you for sharing it. I really dislike the workarounds for things like this and I think it's a genius approach until this stuff is accessible in SwiftUI more naturally.

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

To get the `go` button on the keyboard. Try changing the keyboardtype to .webSearch.

// Tested on Xcode 12 beta 2 and iOS 14

> .keyboardType(.webSearch)

Comment: Great answer. There are other great options for different use cases documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype)

eg. `.keyboardType(.twitter)` and `.keyboardType(.phonePad)`

Answer (score 5):

If somebody is looking for wrapping UITextField in UIViewRepresentable then I have some code to share:

```
struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    let tag: Int
    let placeholder: String
    let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
    let returnVal: UIReturnKeyType

    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var activeFieldTag: Int?
    var totalFields: Int = 0
    @Binding var isSecureTextEntry: Bool
    var textColor: UIColor = .pureWhite
    var font: UIFont = .nexaBold13
    var placeholderTextColor: UIColor = .pureWhite
    var placeholderFont: UIFont = .nexaLight13
    var onEditingChanged: (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }

    var lastActiveFieldTag: Int? {

        // Return, if no active field
        // (It also means textFieldShouldReturn not called yet OR called for last field)
        guard let activeFieldTag = activeFieldTag else {
            return nil
        }
        // Return previous field
        if activeFieldTag > 0 {
            return activeFieldTag - 1
        }
        // Return, if no previous field
        return nil
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.keyboardType = self.keyboardType
        textField.returnKeyType = self.returnVal
        textField.tag = self.tag
        textField.textColor = textColor
        textField.font = font
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(
            string: self.placeholder,
            attributes: [
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: placeholderTextColor,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: placeholderFont,
            ]
        )
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = isSecureTextEntry
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textField: UITextField, context: Context) {
        if textField.text != self.text {
            textField.text = self.text
        }
        handleFirstResponder(textField)
        if textField.isSecureTextEntry != isSecureTextEntry {
            textField.isSecureTextEntry = isSecureTextEntry
        }
    }

    func handleFirstResponder(_ textField: UITextField) {

        // return if field is neither active nor last-active
        if tag != lastActiveFieldTag && tag != activeFieldTag {
            return
        }

        // return if field is already active
        if lastActiveFieldTag == activeFieldTag {
            return
        }

        // It creates problem in UI when we press the next button too fast and continuously on keyboard
        //        // Remove focus from last active field
        //        if lastActiveFieldTag == tag {
        //            uiView.removeFocus()
        //            return
        //        }

        // Give focus to active field
        if activeFieldTag == tag {
            textField.focus()
            return
        }
    }

    // Its called when pressing Next button on the keyboard
    // See textFieldShouldReturn
    func updateNextTag() {
        // There is no next field so set activeFieldTag to nil
        if tag + 1 == totalFields {
            activeFieldTag = nil
        } else {
            // Set next field tag as active
            activeFieldTag = tag + 1
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        var parent: CustomTextField

        init(_ textField: CustomTextField) {
            self.parent = textField
        }

        func updatefocus(textfield: UITextField) {
            textfield.focus()
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            // Give focus to next field
            parent.updateNextTag()
            parent.text = textField.text ?? ""

            // If there is no next active field then dismiss the keyboard
            if parent.activeFieldTag == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    textField.removeFocus()
                }
            } 

            return true
        }

        func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // To enable user to click on any textField while another is active
                self.parent.activeFieldTag = self.parent.tag
                self.parent.onEditingChanged(true)
            }
            return true
        }

        func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            self.parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.onEditingChanged(false)
            }
            return true
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if let text = textField.text, let rangeExp = Range(range, in: text) {
                self.parent.text = text.replacingCharacters(in: rangeExp, with: string)
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why am I getting errors saying `Type 'UIColor' has no member 'pureWhite'` and Value of type 'UITextField' has no member 'focus'? Did something change

Comment: @PeterSchorn Those are not provided by iOS. They must be extensions the OP neglected to provide in their answer.

Answer (score 5):

## iOS 15.0+

macOS 12.0+,
Mac Catalyst 15.0+,
tvOS 15.0+,
watchOS 8.0+

> `submitLabel(_:)`
>
> Sets the submit label for this view.
>
> [https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/submitlabel(_:))

```
Form {
    TextField("Username", $viewModel.username)
        .submitLabel(.done)
}
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.