# How to trigger a method when dismissing keyboard for Text Editor with return key?

Tags: swiftui

Can I change return key function in keyboard? I have already search to change return key function in keyboard but I haven't found the answer.In TextField, when I click return key, keyboard auto dismiss.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008549/is-it-possible-to-change-return-key-to-done-on-keyboard-in-2020-with-swiftui

Comment: Guess you want to trigger something when return key entered ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change "return" key to "done" on keyboard in 2020 with SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008549/is-it-possible-to-change-return-key-to-done-on-keyboard-in-2020-with-swiftui)

Answer (score -1):

You are finding something related to below code which is in `UIKIt` with `UITextFieldDelegate` in `SwiftUI`

In `UIKit` (with `UITextFieldDelegate`)

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      //do something when user press return button
        return true
    }
```

In `SwiftUI`

```swift
  struct ContentView: View {
        @State var text = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $text) {(_) in} onCommit: {
                print("return key pressed") //<= here
               //do something when user press return button
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: References to any of view will not be kept in a variable in `SwiftUI` like we did in `UIKit`

Comment: TextEditor and TextField are not the same.